# Express response.send() object not received by JavaScript fetch() ... why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, fetch

Documentation from Express [response.send](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) allows for objects to be sent in the body, which I am sending as follows:

```
  DBM.saveArticle(obj).then((val) => {
    console.log(val); // verified here
    res.send(val);
    res.end();
    // ... clip here
```

However on the client I am not getting the object.  This is a Create in CRUD, and I am using fetch POST as follows to implement this.

```
    // ... snip
    const options = { 
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
      method: 'POST', 
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    };    
    fetch("/articles/add", options)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('DEBUG: Article Added: ', response); // nothing found here in response
        this.props.dispatch({type: 'addArticle', component_state: state});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('fetch/POST error', error);
      });
      // ... snip
```

console.log from above looks like this, here is a pic, it is empty, as far as I can tell.

[image]

The response object is big, and I tried to click all about it, but it is possible I might have missed something.

The official docs for JavaScript fetch response object is [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Response_objects).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Response_objects

> This is just an HTTP response, not the actual JSON. To extract the JSON body content from the response, we use the json() method (defined on the Body mixin, which is implemented by both the Request and Response objects.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream

> The Fetch API offers a concrete instance of a ReadableStream through
> the body property of a Response object.

`fetch` returns the body as a `ReadableStream` to convert it to a JSON use `response.json()`

```
fetch('https://example.com/profile', {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
.then(response => response.json())   // << this will convert the response to JSON object
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

The data in the ReadableStream is not accessible without consuming the stream, it's stored in a lower-level I/O source, called the underlying source, and there are two types of underlying source: push and pull sources.

In case of HTTP request it's a push source in the form of a TCP socket, where data is constantly being pushed from the OS level, and the data will be accessible to the consumer (your code) once you acquire a lock and start reading it, which is exactly what `json()` method do for you.

refer to this for more details https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#rs-model

Comment: the response body is a stream, so no you can't see it, without consuming it, that's what `.json()` will do

Comment: I ran a search for ReadableStream [here on MDN doc for fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Response_objects) and nothing came up.